# Python Pandas: User defined function missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have defined the function that takes two arguments and returns two values. It looks like as below:

```
def normalized_Value(x,RY):
    Norm = 0
    if RY >= 2016:
        if x > 3.382:
            x = 3.382 #return 3.382
            Norm = 1
        else:
            x = x
        #return x
        return x,Norm
    else:
        if x > 11.93:
            x = 11.93 #return 3.382
            Norm = 1
        else:
            x = x
        #return x
        return x,Norm
```

I called the function in dataframe to create two new columns in the dataframe. I used following code to call the function:

```
df['Normalized_val'], temp['Normalized val event'] = zip(*temp[['value','RY']].apply(normalized_Value))
```

However, when I ran the code it throws an error message of missing argument,

```
TypeError: normalized_Value() missing 1 required positional argument: 'RY'
```

I am passing two arguments in the code, not sure why it is throwing an error message. Could anyone help in rectifying the issue?

Comment: Something's off. By any chance, do these three names refer to the same function: `normalized_Value`, `normalized_val` and `normalized_SAIDI` ?

Comment: Sorry, it was wired mistake. Copied from old code. Now fixed

Comment: If you would like `normalized_Value` to work on two values, you could have it accept a tuple and split it internally. e.g. `def normalized_Value(pair): x, RY = pair` because pandas would just supply your function with a single argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code

```
def normalized_Value(x,RY):
    Norm = 0
    if RY >= 2016:
        if x > 3.382:
            x = 3.382 #return 3.382
            Norm = 1
        else:
            x = x
        #return x
        return [x,Norm]
    else:
        if x > 11.93:
            x = 11.93 #return 3.382
            Norm = 1
        else:
            x = x
        #return x
        return [x,Norm]



s=pd.DataFrame(temp.apply(lambda x : normalized_Value(x['value'],x['RY']),axis=1).tolist() 
                                                               ,index = temp.index, columns=['Normalized_val','Normalized val event'])
temp=temp.join(s)
```

Comment: It returns o and 1 only

Comment: @user2293224 I have not change anything with your function

Comment: this line pd.DataFrame(temp.apply(lambda x : normalized_Value(x['value'],x['RY']),axis=1).tolist() ,index = temp.index) returns the correct values. Problem comes in when assign back to variables